# If judges are appointed, why should law makers be elected?

Tags: election, judiciary, state-legislatures

I'm from the UK. I think the following reasons are why we appoint judges instead of electing them:

1. Appointed judges make decisions that are more independent and unbiased, because they only care about the law instead of earning votes from the people.
2. Majority of the voters do not understand the details and complexity of the legal system in order to decide which candidate is a better judge.
3. Appointed judges have less chance of being corrupted by donations or funding.

Can we not say the same thing for law makers?

1. Appointed law makers make decisions that are more independent and unbiased, because they only care about making good laws instead of earning votes from the people.
2. Majority of the voters do not understand the details and complexity of the economy / legal system / foreign affairs / military / etc in order to decide which candidate is a better law maker.
3. Appointed law makers have less chance of being corrupted by donations or funding.

Comment: Is your question addressed to what country?

Comment: I'm from the UK. However, I'm interested to know what other countries think as well :)

Comment: This is totally opinion based.

Comment: Yes, you could say the same thing. That wouldn't be much of a democracy, though.

Comment: Don't worry, between government bureaucrats, [QUANGOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quango), international agreements and the EU Commission, this is already happening. Parliament still has to vote on statutes but it's only a small part of the law nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

In America, there are two countries who elect their judges via elections: United States and Bolivia. Their experiences are similar with (in my opinion) negative terms.

In Bolivia, this change was lead by Evo Morales, which in the frame of the new Constitution (2009) and, considering the *"refunding"* of the country gave the people the power to choose their national judges with the same criteria applied in a legislative election. In 2011, they chose 28 members of four judicial body: The Supreme Court, the Constitutional Court, the Agro-Enviromental Court and Judicial Council. One interesting attribute for example is that electoral and political campaigns were forbidden; the media interviewed all the candidates, equally and the Electoral Court made an official presentation of all candidates.

The main problem with this election was the political disputes between the government and the opposition. Some analysts argued that the Electoral Court was more friendly with candidates supported by Morales, which cannot be proved but the fact that most of the judges that won the elections were pro-Gov, reinforces the opposition's hypothesis. The second argument is how the judges are pre-selected. According to their laws, all judges must pass through a pre-selection made by the National Assembly, controlled by the Government, giving more doubts about how fair is really this kind of elections.

Another country I mentioned before was the United States. In United States, judges are allowed to make electoral propaganda. This is bad for two reasons:

- Reason number 1: The elections of judges through electoral process is wrong because they're not politicians. Imagine you have a company destroying the environment in your community and the judge elected is a friend of this company because they helped him to raise funds in their campaigns. For pragmatism, we know politicians responds to their sponsors, therefore I can assume that a judge will act in the same way.
- Reason number 2: According to a study quoted in [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/united-states/21613276-theyre-not-politicians-so-they-shouldnt-act-them-trouble-electing-judges), shown that only in Texas almost 83% of Texans thought that campaigns contributions explained in reason number 1, influenced judicial decisions. And this wouldn't be so bad, but happen this:

  > More worryingly, 48% of the judges agreed. Those numbers are unlikely to have improved since.

So, in conclusion for your question: theoretically, elect an authority means the participation of people but the experience show us how can this fair process be contaminated with political vicious.

Sources for Bolivia's experience:

[Reuters Q&A](http://lta.reuters.com/article/domesticNews/idLTASIE7A7Q0E20111013?pageNumber=1&virtualBrandChannel=0)

[La Razón - Judicial section](http://www.la-razon.com/index.php?_url=/suplementos/la_gaceta_juridica/Consideraciones-eleccion-jueces-voto-popular_0_2006199443.html)

Answer (score 0):

Laws should be made by people with scientific degrees in the field of law and in fields related to the law eg. energy/Economics/computer sicence. This could help improve quality of laws and reduce the possibility of loopholes, especially those subtle ones that some politician paid by big companies might overlook.

Politicians should only drive the direction and strategy of laws to be released and review the laws that are going to be released on compliance with those strategies.

As an example the anti-hacker laws in Germany, that were vague enough to shut down anyone related to computer security until a judge of highest instance ruled what is legal and what is not.

This is not the first time (in Germany) that politicians released laws and policies that were so bad that judges had to decide if they are actually legally binding and compliant with the constitution. Or if they have to be changed.

Comment: I'd argue that's how it works now; laws are generally written by interest groups rather than legislators.